# how to create an e commerce html template into WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I upload the theme in wp-content but what is the next step? how I make it changeable? If I create a new page then its design does not work for me hoW I correct it?

Comment: maybe start with a wordpress tutorial

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way wordpress works is very different than simple html. And don't imagine that wordpress will have a page like `Contact.php` and you'll just go and make changes directly. (Although, it could have but very rare)

So, you need to understand wordpress file structure for theme to get started.

Here are two useful resources to get you started:

1. [Converting html site to wordpress](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites)
2. [HTML to wordpress theme](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/html-to-wordpress-theme-tutorial-step-1-converting-your-html-to-php/)

**Additional info about your question:**

In most cases, when you view a page; wordpress pulls page content from database and use `page.php` template to render and display page content inside browser. This principal will apply to all pages including home, about, contact etc.

To make any change in the page, you don't need to edit `page.php`, you have to navigate to Pages inside wordpress dashboard. There you can edit page content for the specific page (e.g home).

PS: there's another approach in which you can create `.php` file for each of your page but that's bad practice because it makes management difficult. So I don't recommend.